# How to check all checkbox when check on one checkbox and click on a button and get the values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for single id i did like this but how to get all id on click of button when check the universal checkbox for all the columns
 My Html File:-

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="option" value="{{item.customerid}} " required ></td>
 <input type="button" value="Transfer" (click)="getclickedevent($event)">
```

My Javascript file:-

```
 getclickedevent(event) {

  let id  = $("input:checkbox[name=option]:checked").val();

    console.log("The Required checkbox checked is "+ id)

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

make all the id's children of one master id

then use this

```
var div = // getElementById, etc
var children = div.childNodes;
var elements = [];
for (var i=0; i<div.childNodes.length; i++) {
  var child = div.childNodes[i];
  if (child.nodeType == 1) {
    elements.push(child)      
  }
}
```

Comment: you can get all the children elements of a parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all checked checkboxes values inside button click event handler using jquery [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) method like:

```
var ids = $("input:checkbox[name=option]:checked").map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

console.log(ids) //==> ['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', ...]
```

This will give a basic array containing all checked checkboxes values.

DEMO:

```js
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
  $("input:checkbox[name=option]").prop('checked', this.checked);

  var ids = $("input:checkbox[name=option]:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  console.log(ids)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">Check All
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="1">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="2">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="3">Item3
```

Comment: this is fine ..But I have one universal checkbox in which if i check and click the button all checkbox should be checked and we should be able to get all the values

Comment: You can check all checkboxes easily like: `$("input:checkbox[name=option]").prop( "checked", true );` I have added a demo to help understand.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind but I took the approach of refactoring your code.

Here is the HTML:

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="{{item.customerid}}" required >
</td>
<input type="button" value="Transfer">

<div id='options'>
  <br><input name='options' type="checkbox">
  <br><input name='options' type="checkbox">
  <br><input name='options' type="checkbox">
  <br><input name='options' type="checkbox">
  <br><input name='options' type="checkbox">
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery. I used jQuery because you missed native javascript and jQuery in your code:

```
$('input[type="button"][value="Transfer"]').click( function() {  
  let id  = $("input:checkbox[name=option]").is(':checked');

    $('input[name="options"]').each(function() { 
        this.checked = id; 
      });
});
```

You can see it all working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sisko/7gou8syd/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. ↓↓

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'customer_store\']').prop('checked', this.checked);"/> Select / Deselect<br>
 
 <input type="checkbox" name="customer_store[]" value="xyz"/>xyz<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="customer_store[]" value="abc"/>abc<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ID to your button inputs and call on them as selectors for `.click()`.

Add a function to get the click on the select all button and set all inputs to checked used an added class of `option` for to select the input elements that are check boxes.

Define an empty array to hold your values. Run your checked values through `.each()` loop and assign them to the array.

Those values will now live in the `options` array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectall').click(function(){
        $('.option').prop("checked", true);
    });
  $('#transfer').click(function() {
    var options = [];
    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function() {
      options .push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(options);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="option" type="checkbox" name="option" value="{{item.customerid}}">
<input class="option" type="checkbox" name="option" value="{{item.customerid}}">
<input class="option" type="checkbox" name="option" value="{{item.customerid}}">
<input class="option" type="checkbox" name="option" value="{{item.customerid}}">

<input type="button" id="transfer" value="Transfer">
<input type="button" id="selectall" value="Select All">
```